# how to map a LinkedHashMap with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I would like to map a LinkedHashMap with Hibernate (annotation driven).

I know the property @MapKey and @IndexColumn, but can I used both to map a linkedhashmap with basics strings ?

Please don't give a solution where I must externalize pet to a class and use a Pet list instead of a LinkedHashMap (I know how to do that but I clearly don't want to do this).

my class :

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> pets;

    // map definition ?
    // id of the pet > name of the pet
    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getPets()
    {
        return pets;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `@Lob` annotation: the LinkedHashMap will be serialized and stored in a BLOB column (and deserialized when read from the database).

But this is of course fragile, impossible to query, forces the use of Java to read the contents of the pets.

If you need a more traditional mapping to an additional Pet table, with a one-to-many association, then you'll need a Pet entity.

Comment: are there some problems when I change java version due to serialVersionUid ? Because I can't loose data just by changing java version.

Comment: You may hope that future versions will stay backwards-compatible, but changing the Java implementation will certainly break it. I wouldn't count on it. You might want to use a custom type which would serialize to XML or JSON, but I would go with an entity mapped to a table: much more standard, efficient, queryable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Just stubled upon this because I'm trying to learn Hibernate (version 3)

I've done something like this to sort on the database side: 
You can't map a LinkedHasMap directly to Hibernate because it's not a collection, it's an implementation of a collection.

You can do something like this:

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "PERSON_PET", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "PET_KEY")
@Column(name = "PET_NAME")
@OrderBy(clause = "lower(PET_NAME) asc")
private Map<String, String> pets = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Quote from [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/)

> You can order by any column of the collection table. Internally, Hibernate uses a
>   LinkedHashMap, a variation of a map that preserves the insertion order of key elements.
>   In other words, the order that Hibernate uses to add the elements to the
>   collection, during loading of the collection, is the iteration order you see in your
>   application. The same can be done with a set: Hibernate internally uses a
>   LinkedHashSet. In your Java class, the property is a regular Set/HashSet, but
>   Hibernate’s internal wrapping with a LinkedHashSet is again enabled with the
>   order-by attribute

Answer (score 1):

You may use `@ElementCollection` annotation to map a map of basic types. Should look like

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_pets", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @OrderColumn(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "pet")
    private Map<String, String> pets = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: that's not a good solution because you only map a classic hashmap and I want to map a LinkedHashMap with order.

Comment: You're right. We can try @OrderColumn, however I couldn't find any evidence that this annotation is usable with Map. (updated the example)

Comment: At the very least `@OrderColumn` requires an integral type: see API docs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html: "The order column must be of integral type." Even if that worked internally as `LinkedHashMap`, I don't see while "keying" into a map by integer should be more advantageous than indexing into a simple list...